# Is it possible to make @Formula annotation lazily loaded?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, annotations

I have used `@Formula` annotation to use it for getting calculated properties. What I need is that those fields/getters which is annotated with `@Formula` annotation should be lazily loaded.

Is this even possible and if so how?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes . Just annotating the fields/getter of the `@Formula` property by [@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html#fetch%28%29) and use this [ant task](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/instrument/javassist/InstrumentTask.html) provided by hibernate to do the  bytecode instrumentation for the entity class. Otherwise ,  LAZY loading for the `@Formula` property is silently ignored.

The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties) contains the info on how to use this ant task to do bytecode instrumentation.

Comment: thanks for your answer, what about maven? is there a way to achive this "bytecode instrumentation" thing in maven? Because I am using maven and have nothing to do with ant.

Comment: you can use `maven-antrun-plugin` plugin which can run Ant tasks within Maven. See :http://doginpool.blogspot.com/2012/03/bytecode-instrumentation-for-hibernate.html

Comment: Bytecode instrumentation in maven:

http://tricksdev.blogspot.ru/2009/03/hibernate-bytecode-instrumentation.html

Comment: Instrumentation class `org.hibernate.tool.instrument.cglib.InstrumentTask` is deprecated, use `org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask` instead.

Source: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/tool/instrument/cglib/InstrumentTask.html

Answer (score 4):

I saw in the comment that you would like to achieve this without bytecode instrumentation. This can be achieved by implementing the `FieldHandled` interface and by modifying the getters and setters for the lazy field.

**HBM**

```
<property name="deletable" type="true_false" lazy="true">
  <formula>(select something from other tables and such....)</formula>
</property>
```

**JAVA**

```
import org.hibernate.bytecode.javassist.FieldHandled;
import org.hibernate.bytecode.javassist.FieldHandler;
public class Person implements FieldHandled {

/* allows lazy formulas without hibernate bytecode instrumentation */
private FieldHandler fieldHandler;
public FieldHandler getFieldHandler() { return fieldHandler; }
public void setFieldHandler(FieldHandler fieldHandler) { this.fieldHandler = fieldHandler; }


private Boolean deletable;

public void setDeletable(Boolean deletable) {
    if(fieldHandler!=null)
        fieldHandler.writeObject(this, "deletable", this.deletable, deletable);
    this.deletable = deletable;
}

public Boolean getDeletable() {
    if(fieldHandler!=null)
        return (Boolean)fieldHandler.readObject(this, "deletable", deletable);
    return deletable;
}
}
```

Another example can be found [here](http://justonjava.blogspot.com/2010/09/lazy-one-to-one-and-one-to-many.html). But that is lazy loading a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: I tried your solution but I got a NPE on `org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityEntry.isUnequivocallyNonDirty(EntityEntry.java:314)` any idea? And which hibernate version did you use?

Comment: @Kakawait sorry I don't know exactly. I wrote this code a while back and believe it was 3.x (where x is unknown)

Comment: This worked for me : don't bother using the fieldHandler for the setter. It is a formula there is nothing to set in DB

Comment: But I have this problem :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701761/hibernate-saveorupdate-doing-nothing/31705549#31705549 hibernate doesn't want to update regular field on FieldHandled entity,

Comment: Working for me in Hibernate 4.3.11, nice solution.

Comment: I also don't seem to need to override the getter/setter at all with the fieldHandler checks, simply marking the field with @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY), implementing FieldHandled on my entity and providing those basic overriden methods seems to be enough for my container to respond with: HHH000157: Lazy property fetching available for: MyModel

Answer (score 2):

I tried with [BytecodeEnhancement (Maven Plugin)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/bytecode/BytecodeEnhancement.html) but doesnt work.
So I made this:

1. Create a Class (FooFormula.java), map it to the table with
   two field, one for the @id and other for the @Formula.

   ```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "BAR_TABLE")
    public class FooFormula implements Serializable {

     private Long idBarTable;
     private Long formula;

     public FooFormula() {
       super();
     }

     public FooFormula(String idBarTable) {
         super();
         this.idBarTable = idBarTable;
     }    

     @Id
     @Column(name = "ID_BAR_TABLE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
     public Long getIdBarTable() {
         return this.sitidBarTableCodigo;
     }

     public void setIdBarTable(Long idBarTable) {
         this.idBarTable = idBarTable;
     }

     @Formula("(SELECT 1 from DUAL)")
     public Long getFormula() {
       return formula;
     }

     public void setFormula(Long formula) {
       this.formula = formula;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Add this new class (FooFormula.java) as a field to your Entity with @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn

   ```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "BAR_TABLE")
    public class Bar implements Serializable {

     private Long idBarTable;
     private Long somOtherColumn;
     private FooFormula fooFormula;

     public Bar() {
       super();
     }

     public Bar(String idBarTable) {
         super();
         this.idBarTable = idBarTable;
     }    

     @Id
     @Column(name = "ID_BAR_TABLE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
     public Long getIdBarTable() {
         return this.sitidBarTableCodigo;
     }

     public void setIdBarTable(Long idBarTable) {
         this.idBarTable = idBarTable;
     }

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name = "ID_BAR_TABLE", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
     public FooFormula getFooFormula() {
       return fooFormula;
     }

     public void setFooFormula(FooFormula fooFormula) {
       this.fooFormula = fooFormula;
     }
   }
   ```