# hibernate - filter relation at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, runtime, filtering, relation

I have the following POJOs:

```
@Entity(name = "member")
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member {
    @Column(name = "identifier")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int mIdentifier;

    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String mName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "mMembers")
    private Set<Project> mProjects = new HashSet<Project>();

    public int getIdentifier() {
        return mIdentifier;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(final String pName) {
        mName = pName;
    }

    public Set<Project> getProjects() {
        return mProjects;
    }

    public Member() {
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "project")
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {
    @Column(name = "identifier")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int mIdentifier;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Member> mMembers = new HashSet<Member>();

    public int getIdentifier() {
        return mIdentifier;
    }

    public Set<Member> getMembers() {
        return mMembers;
    }

    public Project() {
    }
}
```

The following code fetches a certain project, and returns all members:

```
Project project = (Project) db.load(Project.class, 1);

System.out.println(project);
System.out.println(project.getMembers());
```

How can I filter the members of the project? For example, say I only want the members which name starts with an 'a'. I could do some client-side filtering ofcourse (with Guava & Predicate, for example), but it makes more sense to let Hibernate alter the SQL query.

I am aware of [Hibernate filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters), but I don't think they are intended for this. I think they are more useful for global filtering, and not for ad-hoc relation filtering of one specific object.

Pointers to documentation, terminology, etc are very welcome. I am fairly new to Hibernate, and have difficulties to get the documentation for this question.

**edit**

I tried with criteria. I have two members, "John Snow" and "Snow". The following still returns both members.

```
final Criteria criteria = db.createCriteria(Project.class)
        .createCriteria("mMembers")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("mName", "John Snow"));

for (final Project project : (List<Project>) criteria.list()) {
    System.out.println(project.getIdentifier());

    for (final Member member : project.getMembers()) {
        System.out.println(member.getName());
    }
}
```

Any idea?

**edit (2)**

It looks like a second query is executed, to fetch all members. How can we prevent this, and only rely on the criteria-based data?

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.identifier as identifi1_1_1_,
        mmembers3_.mProjects_identifier as mProject1_1_,
        mmembers1_.identifier as mMembers2_2_,
        mmembers1_.identifier as identifi1_0_0_,
        mmembers1_.name as name2_0_0_ 
    from
        project this_ 
    inner join
        project_member mmembers3_ 
            on this_.identifier=mmembers3_.mProjects_identifier 
    inner join
        member mmembers1_ 
            on mmembers3_.mMembers_identifier=mmembers1_.identifier 
    where
        mmembers1_.name=?
1
Hibernate: 
    select
        mmembers0_.mProjects_identifier as mProject1_1_1_,
        mmembers0_.mMembers_identifier as mMembers2_2_1_,
        member1_.identifier as identifi1_0_0_,
        member1_.name as name2_0_0_ 
    from
        project_member mmembers0_ 
    inner join
        member member1_ 
            on mmembers0_.mMembers_identifier=member1_.identifier 
    where
        mmembers0_.mProjects_identifier=?
Snow
John Snow
```

**edit (3)**

Looking at the first query above, this does not really want I want. In essence, I want two queries:

1. The first queries fetches a certain project. This query selects from table *project*.
2. The second query fetches all members, matching a certain criteria. This query is lazily executed when `getMembers()` is called. This query selects from table *member* and joins on *project_member*.

I do not want to combine this into one query and select from table *project_member*, as this would result in a lot of parsing overhead. I do not want to end up with the cartesian product.

Is this possible?

Comment: Well, how about a criteria or hql?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria - I will study this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, I suggest study criteria and/or hql documentation in hibernate. Making simple example, with criteria you can do the following (I assumend Spring's session factory, but api is same elsewhere):

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Project.class);

List filteredProjects = criteria.createAlias("member", "member") //this will join members entity
        .add( Restrictions.ilike("member.mName", "a", MatchMode.ANYWHERE) ) //this will make like, with ignore case and at start and end
        .list(); //and finally, list your entities
```

If you'd like distinct results for projects, it's also easy, just add one more method:

```
List filteredProjects = criteria.createAlias("member", "member")
        .add( Restrictions.ilike("member.mName", "a", MatchMode.ANYWHERE) )
        .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("mIdentifier"))) //this will make distinct on your id property
        .list();
```

With HQL, second query would look like this:

```
List projects = session.createQuery("select distinct p from Project p join p.mMembers as m where m.mName like :param")
       .setParameter("param", "%a%")
       .list();
```

*Edit:* Your desired functionallity would look something like this:

```
@Entity(name = "project")
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {
    @Column(name = "identifier")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int mIdentifier;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Member> mMembers = new HashSet<Member>();

    public int getIdentifier() {
        return mIdentifier;
    }

    public Set<Member> getMembers() {
        return mMembers;
    }

    public Project() {
    }

    @Formula("<YOUR SQL TO FILTER RESULT>")
    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
    public Set<Member> getFilteredMembers() {
        return mMembers
    }
}
```

But according to this: [Is it possible to make @Formula annotation lazily loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070440/is-it-possible-to-make-formula-annotation-lazily-loaded) you need some additional work to make it work lazily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See my edit. I tried something similar with criteria (I did not include the alias), but without success. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What SQL is generated with double createCriteria? I'm not certain if that's correct way of joining, try with aliases instead

Comment: See edit (2)! I also tried with aliasing, but the second query always happen.

Comment: WEll I just realised, that your getters/setters do not follow java conventions. Try to make it right and retry

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: No setters, and name should be `getmName()` or `setmName()` etc. but judging from what you want in edit(3), you need a `@Formula`

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look to the Formula annotation!

Answer (score 0):

New JPA 2.1 specifies possibility to use ON condition in JOINs:

```
select p from Project p left join p.members m ON m.name like 'a%'
```