# Hibernate SaveOrUpdate doing nothing

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I work with Spring 3.2 and Hibernate 3.6.7.

I have a form that display an entity, the form is submited and the entity is saved. Using the saveOrUpdate method.

It worked until I made my entity class `implements FieldHandled`.
Now saveOrUpdate() does nothing.

I read the Hibernate source code and it says (shortcut) that if the Entity implements FieldHandled and if the FieldHandler is not dirty then does nothing.

here is my code :

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class CustomerContactController {

    ....

    @ModelAttribute
    public CustomerContactAddressDTO getCustomerContactAddress(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        CustomerContactAddressDTO customerContactAddressDTO = new CustomerContactAddressDTO();
        customerAddress = customerAddressDao.findById(customerAddressUid);
        customerContactAddressDTO.setCustomerContact(customerAddress.getCustomerContact());
        return customerContactAddressDTO;       
    }

    @Secured(UserService.ROLE_PREFIX + "right.customer.contact.update")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/customer/contact/formedit/{customerContactAddressDTOUid}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ReturnFormResult formEditSubmit(@ModelAttribute CustomerContactAddressDTO customerContactAddressDTO,
            @PathVariable final String customerContactAddressDTOUid) {

        final CustomerAddress customerAddress = customerContactAddressDTO.getCustomerAddress();

        ReturnFormResult rfr = new ReturnFormResult();
        rfr.setMode("update");
        rfr.setStatus(Boolean.TRUE);

        customerAddressDao.saveOrUpdate(customerAddress);

        return rfr;
    }
}
```

Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_customer_contact_address")
public class CustomerAddress implements FieldHandled{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "customer_contact_address_uid", updatable = false)
    private String id;

    ....

    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Formula("(some native sql query)")
    private String groupTransactionCodes;


    private FieldHandler fieldHandler;

    @Override
    public void setFieldHandler(FieldHandler handler) {
        this.fieldHandler = handler;

    }

    @Override
    public FieldHandler getFieldHandler() {     
        return fieldHandler;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {  
        this.id = id;       
    }

    public String getGroupTransactionCodes() {
        if(fieldHandler!=null){
            return (String)fieldHandler.readObject(this, "groupTransactionCodes", groupTransactionCodes);
        }       
        return groupTransactionCodes;
    }

    public void setGroupTransactionCodes(String groupTransactionCodes) {
        this.groupTransactionCodes = groupTransactionCodes;
    }   
}
```

this is hibernate code source

[image: hibernate]

`!FieldInterceptionHelper.isInstrumented( entity )` = false because my entity is intrumented

`FieldInterceptionHelper.extractFieldInterceptor( entity)` return the fieldHandler of my Entity which is dirty == false

true && ( false || false || false) = false

[image: myfield handler]

hibernate source code :

as  mightBeDirty == false for him update is notNecessary and doesn't schedule update.

[image: hibernate]

My question :
How could I have make the saveOrUpdate() really update in database when I use it on detached entity wich are instrumented ?

Thanks

database configuration :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.XXXX.db.pojo"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.XXXX.application.utils.MSSQLAHEADDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="eventListeners">
            <map>
                <entry key="save-update" value-ref="saveEventListener" />
                <entry key="flush-entity" value-ref="flushEntityEventListener" />
                <entry key="post-load" value-ref="postLoadEventListener" />

            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="saveEventListener" parent="callbackHandlerEventListener" class="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3SaveOrUpdateEventListener" />

    <bean id="flushEntityEventListener" parent="callbackHandlerEventListener" class="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3FlushEntityEventListener" />

    <bean id="postLoadEventListener" parent="callbackHandlerEventListener" class="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostLoadEventListener" />

    <bean id="entityCallbackHandler" class="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EntityCallbackHandler" />

    <bean id="callbackHandlerEventListener" abstract="true" class="org.hibernate.ejb.event.CallbackHandlerConsumer">
        <property name="callbackHandler" ref="entityCallbackHandler" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/dataSourceAHEAD"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Throw hibernate configuration here.

Comment: Have you tried with adding property to hibernate `hibernate.connection.autocommit` and setting this to `true` ?

Answer (score 0):

I hacked by just doing this before saving : 
`customerAddress.getFieldHandler().writeObject(customerAddress, "name", customerAddress.getName(), customerAddress.getName());`

it will force dirty to becode true.
 I feel like when a Entity implements FieldHandled, It prevent any kind of automatic runtime instrumentation.I think I should implement all the setter by hand like this :

```
    public void setXXX(String xxx) {
            getFieldHandler().writeObject(this, "xxx", this.xxx, xxx);
            this.xxx = xxx;
    }
```

calling writeObject by hand in each setter.