# Controlling lazy/eager loading of @Formula columns dynamically

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We have a few entities with a bunch of properties annotated with Hibernate's `@Formula` annotation. The SQL snippets in the annotations mainly run scalar sub-queries (e.g. `COUNT` queries). As an example, we have a one-to-many relationship hierarchy that's four levels deep: `A <- B <- C <- D` (where `<-` marks a one-to-many association). Pretty often when fetching an entity of type `A`, we'd like to know the amount of associated entities of type `D`. For this we use a `@Formula`-annotated property in `A`.

As we don't need these values every time, we've declared the `@Formula` properties as lazy-loaded (we've enabled Hibernate's bytecode enhancement to make this possible). But for some queries, we'd like to load these properties eagerly. We often load hundreds of entities of type `A` in one query, and it'd be important performance-wise to control the eager/lazy loading of these properties dynamically. We already use JPA's entity graphs to control which properties get loaded eagerly for certain queries, but entity graphs don't seem to work here. Even if we list the `@Formula` properties in the entity graph, they're still loaded lazily.

**Is it possible to control lazy/eager loading of `@Formula` columns dynamically on a per query basis?** We're currently restricted to the JPA Criteria Query API, and named queries are not a possibility here.

**Update:**

The properties in question are not associations to other entities, but just some calculated values. This means that e.g. fetch profiles don't apply here, as they're only applicable to entity associations (or at least that's how I understood the [Hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching-profile)). Here's an example of one of our `@Formula` properties:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Formula("(select count(*) from entity_D_table where ...)")
    private int associatedDCount;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Critria api to make it return a DTO instead of an Entity.

In your criteria query use a Projection to select only the column you need.

```
ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.property("id").as("id"));
properties.add(Projections.property("name").as("name"));
properties.add(Projections.property("lazyField").as("lazyField"));
criteria.setProjection(properties);
criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(MyEntityDTO.class));
```

That way the select query will only contains the fields you ask, whatever  the mapping EAGER or LAZY.

Comment: We don't use Hibernate's Criteria API, but I'd guess this is achievable with the JPA Criteria Query API as well. This would require quite a lot of changes in our current codebase, but might be worth it if the current implementation is deemed to slow. Doesn't really solve the immediate problem, but +1 for the idea in any case.

Comment: From my experience using DTO instead of Entity is way better for the performance when I just need to display data : you have the control on the number of join,or column and can create specific index to speed up queries even more

Comment: Well, the amount of joins can be controlled with the JPA entity graphs, and my understanding is that fetching too many columns shouldn't be that big of a performance hit. But yeah, using DTOs like you describe does allow for more control and fine-tuning. At least in our case, though, it would also require more implementation work and increase code complexity, and I don't know if that's a good trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it's not hard to pull this off without having to resort to bytecode instrumentation.

Create a "formula" entity *mapped to the same table*:

```
@Entity
@Table("A")
public class ACounts {
  @Id
  private Long id; 

  @Formula("(select count(*) from entity_D_table where ...)")
  private int dCount;

  public int getDCount() {
    return dCount; 
  }
}
```

Then in your parent entity, `A`, use `@ManyToOne` to relate lazily to this "formula" entity:

```
@Entity
public class A {   
  @Id 
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private ACounts counts;

  public ACounts getCounts() {
    return counts;
  }
  ...
}
```

Now the count query will only be issued when the count is requested (i.e. it's lazy!):

```
A a = ...

// lazily invoke count query now:
a.getCounts().getDCount()
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55581854/225217

Comment: This seems like a clever little trick, but I can't verify whether it works or not, since I left the project in question years ago. But thanks for the suggestion in any case!

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I was hoping to find. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have a look at Hibernate's fetch profiles https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-profiles.

You can for example annotate an entity like that

```
@Entity
@FetchProfile(name = "country_states", fetchOverrides = {
           @FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = Country.class, association = "states", mode = FetchMode.JOIN)
})
public class Country implements Serializable {...
```

and activate the JOIN mode when querying, like this:

```
 session=getSession();
 session.beginTransaction();
 //enable fetch profile for EAGER fetching
 session.enableFetchProfile("country_states");
```

As shown in http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/fetchprofile_hibernate_annotation

Comment: But aren't the fetch profiles only applicable to entity associations? I added a code example of what our properties look like, I don't think the fetch profiles would work here.

Comment: You are right. Could you consider defining a SQL view in your DB and mapping a new entity on it in order to fetch the formula eagerly as a simple property?

Comment: I've been considering creating a view, but that'd require quite a lot of changes in the codebase. Currently we use the JPA entity graphs to eagerly load data from around a dozen tables in one go, and the code expects that it gets the whole entity graph. But if the current approach ends up being too slow in benchmarking, we'll have to think about this again.