# improving hibernate query performance

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to improve query performance but I didn't find the way. I have hibernate entity two derivative properties and one-to-many relation that are queering the same table (voucher) , this will generate 2 sub queries and one join query , is there are way to combine those two sub queries and join query (for one-to-many relation) in one query

I checked that @Formula can be used in Many-to-one relation but not in one-to-many

Here is part of the entity :

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = pool_table)
public class PoolView{

@Formula(value = "(select sum(sum) from Voucher")
  private Double totalSum = 0.0;

  @Formula(value = "(select sum(rank) from Voucher")
  private Double totalRank = 0.0;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = v.id, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @BatchSize(size = 50)
  @JsonProperty("voucher_filters")
  private List<VoucherFilters> vouchersFilters;
}
```

Comment: First of all you have Lazy fetch type, it means that you will get your list only if you are using it. Formulas may be also Lazy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070440/is-it-possible-to-make-formula-annotation-lazily-loaded  If you are not allways need them, it will reduce time of getting the Entity. Can you provide more information about when you use the fields of your Entity? And how do you profile your performance?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have it in one query is to move the two fields totalSum and totalRank to the entity VoucherFilters.

Assuming that the foreign key column in the table Voucher is called pool_tableId then you can your formulas like this

@Formula(value = "(select sum(sum) from Voucher where pool_tableId = pool_table.id")
  private Double totalSum = 0.0;

@Formula(value = "(select sum(rank) from Voucher pool_tableId = pool_table.id")
  private Double totalRank = 0.0;

Another side issue that the JoinColumn annotation in the class PoolView should reference the foreign key column in the table Voucher e.g. pool_tableId